# clickable links inside accordion (HTML CSS ONLY)

Tags: html, css

i made this accordion with checkbox write in only CSS and HTML, however the clickable content inside each accordion is not clickable anymore, because now when i click on it, the accordion just closed,

how can i make the links/videos inside clickable again? Thank you very much in advance,

```css
ul li i:before {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
ul li i:after {
    -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}
ul li input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ p {
    margin-top: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%);
    transform: translate(0, 50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>click <a href="https://www.google.nl/ "> here</a></p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the checkbox is positioned absolutely so when clicking on your link, you are actually still clicking on the checkbox.

To fix this add

```
ul li {
  position: relative;
}
```

and then

```
ul li input ~ p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

So your content appears above the checkbox.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/becLu1v0/

Answer (score -1):

You could use [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) and give your link a class name.

```css
ul li i:before {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
ul li i:after {
    -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}
ul li input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ p {
    margin-top: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%);
    transform: translate(0, 50%);
}

.clickable{
    z-index:100;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p class="clickable">click <a href="https://www.google.nl/ "> here</a></p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```